# How to set "grow" size as max-width in tailwind css?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a layout based on Flexbox.
The `grow` class sets the element size used to place the dynamic content.
Now my content is one big table. I want to make it scrollable (horizontally), but it is not possible to consider a fixed size for its parent (because its size is set by grow)

Simple representation of the structure:

```
<!-- Layout -->
<div class="flex">

    <!-- Sidebar menu -->
    <div class="w-xx">
        ...
    </div>

    <!-- main -->
    <div class="grow h-full">

        <!-- this element should be scrollable -->
        <div>
            ... Big Table ...
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The problem is that instead of being scrollable, the `main` element changes size and goes out of the window.

I tried using JavaScript, but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: You need a max width and have to fiddle around with overflow to get scroll bars.

Comment: @Stefan my sidebar menu have dynamic width and i can`t set any static size for main element

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
<!-- Sidebar menu -->
<div class="w-xx">
    ...
</div>

<!-- main -->
<div class="grow h-full overflow-hidden">

    <div class="w-full h-full overflow-hidden">

        <!-- this element should be scrollable -->
        <div class="overflow-auto">
            ... Big Table ...
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```